# The path or file name for \\...\filename.pptx is invalid. Please check that the path and file name are correct

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

Yesterday I saved my work in my Powerpoint presentation (2007), today the MS Powerpoint shows me this message:

! The path or file name for \...\filename.pptx is invalid. Please check that the path or file name are correct.

File name is correct. Path is correct. 
I think when I saved it, the file somehow got corrupted during saving.

Is there any way, I can with any software open my file for AT LEAST for viewing. 
I do not want to lose all of my very important work.

Comment: Take a look: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813722

Comment: Thank you but my work is not saved online. It's on the hard drive. Any other files, when I open them, open ok. Just this one, does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/927477) on recovering a broken powerpoint file.

If that does not work, try renaming the extension of the file to text document format such as .txt or .rtf - you may be able to at least get the raw text of the presentation to work with.

You could also try a [hex editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). Throw the file inside and see if you can decipher your text. Try saving an empty powerpoint, and compare to your corrupted one - perhaps you can modify the header, footer of the files to get a functional copy again.

Comment: Thank you very much Carrein! Great link. It almost worked. One I have been able to save and recover. 
The other one, It seems that my file is more corrupt than it looks. I tried RTF and TXT but the files once opened are blank. Good idea though.
I am still fighting though.

Comment: Try a hex editor, check my anwser.

Comment: Thank you Carrein. You got some skills. :)
I did that. Saved a blank PPT and compared to my work PPT. 
And what I saw is unbelievable.
While blank one has hex codes all over, my work PPT is ALL zeros. There is absolutely nothing in HEX. And it is 2.3Mb in size, and nothing.
I am using Mac and Virtual Desktop to run MS Powerpoint 2007 within virtual Windows 7 Ultimate. 
Would it make sense to erase my virtual windows and install everything all over again?

Comment: Parallel Desktop, not Virtual Desktop.

Comment: Did you get it working? I don't think reinstalling the OS will do much but you are free to try. I see you are using Powerpoint 2007. Maybe try testing the files using different versions of the software?

Comment: Hm, yea, I dont have that much time.
I did not get it work but I have a backup version of my PPT file. So, I will try do it again. Save it as "Save as" and see if it happens again. 
It is a shame because I have done so much. :/